# Gremlin: select vertex based on comparison of two property values

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Lets say I have the following Gremlin graph:

```
g.addV('test1').property('pkey', 100).property('v1', 100).property('v2', 150)
g.addV('test1').property('pkey', 100).property('v1', 100).property('v2', 75)
```

I want to query for all of the 'test1' labeled vertices where the property value v1 is greater than the property value v2. How do I achieve this in Gremlin?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `where()` step in this fashion:

```
gremlin> g.addV('test1').property('pkey', 100).property('v1', 100).property('v2', 150)
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.addV('test1').property('pkey', 100).property('v1', 100).property('v2', 75)
==>v[4]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('test1').as('a').where('a',gt('a')).by('v1').by('v2')
==>v[4]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('test1').as('a').where(gt('a')).by('v1').by('v2')
==>v[4]
```

Comment: Does this work for you against CosmosDB's Gremlin API? I just tried that, and it returned an empty list.

g.V().hasLabel('test1').valueMap(): 
```
[
  {
    "pkey": [
      100
    ],
    "v1": [
      100
    ],
    "v2": [
      150
    ]
  },
  {
    "pkey": [
      100
    ],
    "v1": [
      100
    ],
    "v2": [
      75
    ]
  }
]
```

g.V().hasLabel('test1').as('a').where(gt('a')).by('v1').by('v2'):

Comment: i included the longhand version where you explicitly specify the initial comparing step label for `where()` - perhaps that works with CosmosDB? if that doesn't work you might need to raise a bug report to them.