# How to filter for vertices with a property who's value equals their own id (using Gremlin)

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3, graphdb

I want to get all *v*'s s.t *v.id == v.prop1* for some property named *prop1* (which has a string value).

I'm able to compare 2 props of the same vertex thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56031743/12046557) using:

```
g.V().as('v').where(eq('v')).by('prop1').by('prop2')
```

but using:

```
g.V().as('v').where(eq('v')).by(id()).by('prop1')
```

Doesn't work and returns an empty response.

After a quick investigation I realized that the equality check fails due to UUID not being the same type as string.
I also saw one approach to change the configuration on how gremlin calculates equality.

Is there any way to do that without changing the configuration of my graph?
Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the tags , are you using these queries with Amazon Neptune? If so, all Neptune IDs are strings, so, as long as the property is also a string the comparison should work.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence thanks for your answer.
unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: OK - I'll add an answer with a working example

Answer (score 0):

In the example below we find `V(3)` and then look for a vertex with an `id` property, that matches the ID for `V(3)`

```java
// Create a test vertex
g.addV('test').property('id','3')

v[8ebf4e34-073f-10b6-c6c9-f553b3a81e6c]

// Find any matches
g.V('3').as('a').V().has('id').where(eq('a')).by('id').by(id())

v[8ebf4e34-073f-10b6-c6c9-f553b3a81e6c]
```

You can re-arrange the query any way you like, but the key is that there has to be something to compare to. Otherwise you are looking for any vertex that has an `id` and `"id"` property that are the same - probably not what you are looking for.